# Вывод масива через foreach с конца до начала

Tags: php, массивы

```
$array=array('a','b','c','d','f');

foreach ($array as $a){
echo '<br/>'
echo $a;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы массив выводило с конца до начала.
Пр. f,d,c,b,a

Comment: http://codepad.org/3JOCAqAo

Comment: помогло спасибо!

Comment: нет проблем

Answer (score 4):

**array_reverse()** а дальше **foreach**

и при чем тут тег yii???

Comment: я использую framework yii

Comment: @d_php ну слава богу, теперь-то понятно1

Answer (score 0):

Максимально быстрый вариант без лишних операций реверса и копирования.

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'];

for(end($arr); !is_null(key($arr)); prev($arr))
    echo '<br/>', current($arr);
```

Вариант с ключом.

```
$arr = ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C', 'd' => 'D', 'f' => 'F'];

for(end($arr); !is_null(($key = key($arr))); prev($arr))
    echo '<br/>', $key, ': ', current($arr);
```